# Insert MAVEN_OPTS in the POM.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I must increase java heap space to compile my project. The only way I found is modify mvn.bat and set:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms1300M -Xmx1300M
```

than all colleagues must change the file localy. 
I want keep all inside my project, not localy. Can I insert in the POM.xml or other file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting MAVEN_OPTS usually provides arguments to the JVM running the build, and these are passed down to the compiler because it runs inline. You have probably already noted that the `maven-surefire-plugin` used for test usually fork a separate process so passing options to the plugin is bound inside the pom.xml.

What if you fork the compilation process also and add the flags there, such as the below example.

Notice the fork and the compiler args

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
          <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
          <compilerArgument>-verbose -bootclasspath ${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```