# Append to java.library.path in `jvmArguments` some path

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am using spring-boot and maven. I managed to overwrite `java.library.path` in `jvmArguments` tag. However, I would like to append a path to `java.library.path`.  Can I do this in the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: you can add -Djava.library.path to your MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this variable in pom.xml ?

Comment: You can try solution mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672992/insert-maven-opts-in-the-pom-xml

Answer (score 1):

In production: in the pom edit the spring-boot-maven-plugin's , add
              true
              -Djava.library.path=./libs
This will add the parameter to the startup script, if you have a self executing spring-boot. obviously, if you're running inside container (e.g. tomcat), you have to edit the startup parameters there.

For integration testing use the maven-surefire-plugin, and set this here:

```
    <configuration>
      <environmentVariables>
        <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${project.basedir}/libs</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>
      </environmentVariables>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <java.library.path>./libs</java.library.path>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
```

taken from http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Also the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set here, so that on linux-systems dependent libraries can be loaded.  If you only have one library, you don't need the `<environmentVariables>` part.

BTW: If you add the java.library.path to the maven commandline, this won't work, because surefire fires up its own jvm.